# express.io Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, express.io

How do I set up express.io when I have files for each route. I'm struggling to apply the [examples](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples#simple-http--io-setup).

I have a standard Express I'm trying to convert to express.io:

```
Project
    app.js
    routes
       servepage.js
    Views
       servepage.jade
    public
       main.js   <-- client side javascript
```

In the Routing example, they put this code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express.io');
  .... lots of Express routes omitted
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.emit('talk', {
        message: 'io event from an io route on the server'
    })
})
```

I put just the route definition in app.js:

```
app.io.route('ready', servepage);
```

and get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How do I set up the app using more than just app.js? And why is it giving me this error?

EDIT:
The servepage.js file has:

```
var express = require('express');
```

and not:

```
var express = require('express.io');
```

because this generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you omit the require statement of servepage.js file

servepage.js

```
module.exports = function(){ ... };
```

app.js

```
var servepage = require("./routes/servepage.js");
app.io.route('ready', servepage);
```

Comment: Hi, I do add it in - apologies for omitting it from the question, there is quite a long list of 'regular' (non express.io) routes.